# using sharepoint OOTB DragDrop.js library in Custom webpart

Tags: sharepoint-online, rest, client-object-model

I implemented drag and drop file upload functionality with using REST api in my webpart .
But i found an OOTB sharepoint dragdrop.js library which has numerous methods to create drag drop control. 
 Does anyone has an example to create a dragdrop control using this OOTB dragdrop.js?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you get any pointers for achieving this?